# Reading from a socket closed by peer

Tags: sockets

Suppose we have A and B connected by socket. If A writes some data and then closes socket, would B be able to read that data?

Comment: It depends on the protocol and the socket options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question comes up from time to time on SO.  Read the web page below, "The ultimate so_linger page"

http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable

I think the jury is still out, but my recommendation is for the server to call shutdown() to indicate it is done sending.  Then the client closes his socket upon recv() returning 0.  Server closes his socket upon recv returning 0 or after a reasonable timeout.